# PS3 Controller Connects/Disconnects Constantly

Tags: ps3, controllers, motioninjoy-ds3tool

I've been using MotionInJoy's DS3 tool to use my PS3 controllers to play games on my computer (specifically emulators like VBA, since Mother 3 can not be played legitimately in the US). It has worked fine until a couple of days ago when my controller began to connect and disconnect constantly.

I can't play Mother 3 anymore without the controller popping in and out repeatedly. I tried resetting my controller's sync with the PS3, but that didn't help, and the batteries are fully charged.

I think this might have something to do with the USB connector I'm using (it came with a PSP kit I got many a year ago, and it's worked well with charging my PS3 controllers, so I kept it for that purpose), but does anyone know how to fix this or what might really be causing the problem?

Comment: So you're playing it wired, right? It sounds like the cable is just disconnecting intermittantly. Have you tried using bluetooth or a different miniUSB cable?

Comment: Yeah, this one seems to be working better. I'm guessing the old one just went bad?

Comment: Bad contacts or a loose connection can mean the slightest bump loses the physical connection, and you'll get the situation you're having here

Comment: I've had this issue with a bad cable, using a different cable fixed the issue.  It could also be an issue with the port/controller.

Answer (score 1):

Tips for people who are using DS3 Tool and the Mini USB cord.

1. **Disable vibration** - On the homepage of DS3 Tool there is a Motor slider % and you need to set this to 0 on both left and right motors (zero). This is the main cause for wired disconnections. The internal motors will loosen  the Mini Usb port connection on the top of the controller.
2. **Physically move the controller** with a casual motion up and down to test the Mini USB connection - If your PS3 controller is still having problems with disconnections, it might be a worn out Mini USB port on the controller port itself from using the cord for previous usage charging the controller.